# Creating a new method for a generic from another package in R

Tags: r, class, generics, methods, package

In R, what is the simplest way to include a new method for a generic in another package?  For example, the 'nlme' package has a generic called 'getData" with methods for objects of class 'lme' and 'nls'.  I would simply like to add a method for objects of class 'lm' in my own package.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add another method to an existing S3 generic such as `getData` from `nlme`, just create a function named `getData.classname`. For example, say I have a special object of class "foo"

```
z <- structure(5, class="foo")
```

I just define

```
getData.foo<-function(x, ...) {
    unclass(x)+5
}
```

then when I call

```
library(nlme)
getData(z)
#[1] 10
```

my custom function is called. It's all about naming your function correctly. That's it.

Comment: Good knowledge.  I'll be needing this soon.

Comment: My method works as you describe, but in the NAMESPACE roxygen lists it as `export(as.data.table.xts)` instead of `S3method(as.data.table.xts)`, is this a problem/unusual?

Comment: @mkemp6 From what I gather [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html), it looks like you would want `S3method(as.data.table, xts)` in the NAMESPACE file of your package.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant. I'm wondering why roxygen2 creates the entry in the NAMESPACE as `export(...)` even though a generic exists for in a required package

Comment: @mkemp6 I'm not sure. If you really want to know, I would suggesting opening a new question about that specifically.